# small jquery extension doesnt work

Tags: jquery

after trying several ways of (first time) creating an extension to jQuery... and it doesn't work yet:

```
(function($){ 
$.fn.fixInputWidthsForBlog = function() 
{ 
console.log('hi extension');
// var w = $('#newblogentryform input[name="headline"]').outerWidth();
// $('#newblogentryform textarea[name="text"]').outerWidth(w); 
// $('#newblogentryform submit[name="submit"]').outerWidth(w); 
}; // endFUNC
}(jQuery));
```

this (following) is where i get an error:

> "jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $.fixInputWidthsForBlog is not a function"

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.fixInputWidthsForBlog(); 
    alert('ok1'); 
    $(window).on('resize', function(){ $.fixInputWidthsForBlog(); });
    $('.linkNewBlogEntry').on('click',function() { 
        $('#newblogentryformdiv').slideToggle().delay(1200).fixInputWidthsForBlog(); 
        // setTimeout("fixInputWidthsForBlog();",1200); 
        return false;   
        }); 
});
```

I also tried:

```
$.fn.extend({
    fixInputWidthsForBlog = function() {} 
});
```

and simply:

```
$.fn.fixInputWidthsForBlog = function() {};
```

but all of them result in this very same error:

> "jquery-3.1.0.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $.fixInputWidthsForBlog is not a function"

in the line where I try to execute:

```
$.fixInputWidthsForBlog();
```

in one way or another.

Comment: Do you really mean to call this *not* on jQuery sets (`$.fixInputWidthsForBlog();`) rather than on jQuery sets (`$(...).fixInputWidthsForBlog();`)?

Comment: thx @eisbehr:  i tried the editing several times, i m still new to this :)

Comment: @Crowder  : yes, i d like to chain (2nd option) - and don't yet quite understand the difference really,  ... :(

Comment: [eisbehr's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39466109/157247) should be useful then (look at the `onElements` part of it). I've also written up plugin examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227873/troubles-writing-a-proper-jquery-plugin/11227903#11227903) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626734/can-you-use-a-js-object-as-the-interface-for-a-jquery-plugin/21626778#21626778), FWIW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending `$.fn` only works for element chains, not as own function of the jQuery object. For this you need to extend `$` directly, without `fn`.

```js
(function($) {
    // jQuery plugin
    $.fn.onElements = function() {
        console.log('hi, element chain plugin');

        // make chainable
        return this;
    };

    // jQuery object extension
    $.onjQuery = function() {
        console.log('hi, jQuery object extension');
    };
}(jQuery));

// will work
$('someElementSelector').onElements();
$('someElementSelector').onElements().onElements();
$.onjQuery();

// will not work
// $('someElementSelector').onjQuery();
// $.onElements();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: well,... so I got one last question: 
(how) would it be possible to use the same function for both?
... yet thinking about it, it's not necesary I guess, since I can find onElements solutions for every situation that I need. 
 Thank you so much! :)

Comment: In general: `$.fn.myPlugin = $.myPlugin = function() {};`. But you need to implement everything compatible then. It's a bit tricky sometimes. ;) @davidman77

Comment: very cooool! i had "imagined" sth like that, thanx!